# Get user IP in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way to get the IP of the person accessing the shiny app? Hopefully there's a R/Shiny solution but I can accept a javascript solution as well. I want to reverse geocode the IP to make graphs that visualize which countries most users access the app from -- and then put that information in the app for all users to see. I only need a way to get the users IP, the other things are easily solveable.

Comment: Have a look here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html and here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html

Answer (score 8):

You can try this. 
In the folder `www`, put this file, say `getIP.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    Shiny.onInputChange("getIP", response);
  }, "json");
});
```

In `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src="getIP.js")
  ),
  .......
```

And in `server.R` (the observer is just for testing):

```
  IP <- reactive({ input$getIP })

  observe({
    cat(capture.output(str(IP()), split=TRUE))
  })
```

Then you get such a list as the output of `IP()` (I hide my IP):

```
List of 8
 $ ip      : chr "xx MY IP IS HERE xx"
 $ hostname: chr "No Hostname"
 $ city    : chr "Liège"
 $ region  : chr "Wallonia"
 $ country : chr "BE"
 $ loc     : chr "50.6412,5.5718"
 $ org     : chr "AS12392 Brutele SC"
 $ postal  : chr "4020"
```

This is not perfect, sometimes the result is `NULL`.

Comment: I checked your solution, and it seems it has two limitations @Stephane.

It returns only the IP address of the session from which the user is firing the shiny app. That is not terribly useful as a user knows his own IP. It is the admin that has to gather IP addresses of all users connecting to the shiny app.

It returns IP only once while if we need IP along with each input from the users, how can we achieve that?

With the above two clarifications your solution would become undoubtedly hugely acceptable.

Comment: Sorry @SanjayMehrotra, no idea.

Comment: @LazarusThurston in the server you could include some code that stores the IP address to some sort of a storage I guess.

Answer (score 3):

dont say so much. show code again

```
library(shiny)  
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script('$(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized",function(){$.get("https://api.ipify.org", function(response) {Shiny.setInputValue("getIP", response);});})'),
  verbatimTextOutput('ip')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ip <- reactive(input$getIP)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2):

dont say so much, show code here

```
library(shiny)  
ui <- fluidPage(
  # get ip
  tags$script(src="http://pv.sohu.com/cityjson?ie=utf-8"),
  tags$script('$( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {Shiny.setInputValue("too",returnCitySN["cip"]);});'),         
  
  # print
  verbatimTextOutput("ip")      
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ip <- renderPrint(input$too) 
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```