# How to avoid R Shiny users to answer multiple times?

Tags: r, shiny

When creating a questionnaire as an R Shiny app (hosted on shiny servers), what are the possible strategies **to avoid or limit users from answering multiple times**?

For instance, one strategy would be to ask for an email address and validate this field. However, a fake email address could be added, or a user could have multiple email addresses.

I know there is no perfect solution, but a mix of existing strategies could help. What are the most useful strategies?

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: **Use the user IP address**

Which you can get with `session$request$REMOTE_ADDR` (for details see also [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888099/get-user-ip-in-shiny)). Disadvantage: of course, users can hide their address behind a proxy. And many users do not have unique IPs to begin with.

Solution 2: Use all the settings from **[`session$clientData`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html)** to create a user profile that goes beyond just the IP. But you can switch browsers. You can switch to different devices, etc.

Solution 3: Set a **cookie**. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353680/how-to-access-browser-session-cookies-from-within-shiny-app) (which only looks at session cookies though). Disadvantages: you have to ask users to permit cookies and they can always delete them.

Solution 4: the best solution I can think of is a **3rd party tracking tool** like Google analytics or Mamoto. Such tools provide a user id. You can find more about this [in the Shiny articles](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html).

Such tools provide snippets of Javascript code that you need to include in the HTML head:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(
     // Copy and paste from 3rd party tool
    ))),
    ...  
)
```